# Dummify categorical variables for logistic regression with pandas and scikit (OneHotEncoder)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I read [this](https://medium.com/dunder-data/from-pandas-to-scikit-learn-a-new-exciting-workflow-e88e2271ef62) blog about new things in `scikit`. The `OneHotEncoder` taking strings seems like a useful feature. Below my attempt to use this

```py
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

cols = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Embarked']

train_df = pd.read_csv('../../data/train.csv', usecols=cols)
test_df = pd.read_csv('../../data/test.csv', usecols=[e for e in cols if e != 'Survived'])

train_df.dropna(inplace=True)
test_df.dropna(inplace=True)

X_train = train_df.drop("Survived", axis=1)
Y_train = train_df["Survived"]
X_test = test_df.copy()

ct = ColumnTransformer([("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['Sex', 'Embarked'])], remainder='passthrough')

X_train_t = ct.fit_transform(train_df)
X_test_t  = ct.fit_transform(test_df)

print(X_train_t[0])
print(X_test_t[0])

# [ 0.    1.    0.    0.    1.    0.    3.   22.    1.    0.    7.25]
# [ 0.    1.    0.    1.    0.          3. 34.5     0.    0.  7.8292]

logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000)
logreg.fit(X_train_t, Y_train)
Y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_t) # ValueError: X has 10 features per sample; expecting 11
acc_log = round(logreg.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)

print(acc_log)
```

I encounter the below python error with this code and also I have some additional concerns.

> ValueError: X has 10 features per sample; expecting 11

To start from the beginning .. this script is written for the "titanic" dataset from kaggle. We have five numerical columns `Pclass`, `Age`, `SibSp`, `Parch` and `Fare`. The columns `Sex` and `Embarked` are categories `male/female` and `Q/S/C` (which is an abbreviation for a city name).

What I understood from the `OneHotEncoder` is that it creates dummy variables by placing additional columns. Well actually the output of `ct.fit_transform()` is no longer a pandas dataframe but a `numpy` array now. But as seen in the print debug statement there are more than the original 7 columns now.

There are three problems I encounter:

1. For some reason the `test.csv` has one less column. That would indicate to me that there is on less option in one of the categories. To fix that i would have to find all the available options in the categories over both train + test data. And then use these options (such as male/female) to transform the train and the test data separately. I have no idea how to do this with the tools i'm working with (`pandas`, `scikit`, etc). On second thought .. after inspecting the data i can not find the missing option in the `test.csv` ..
2. I want to avoid the "[dummy variable trap](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/dummy-variable-trap-c6d4a387f10a)".  Right now it seems that there are too many columns created. I was expecting 1 column for Sex (total options 2 - 1 to avoid trap) and 2 for embarked. With the additional 5 numerical columns that would come to 8 total.
3. I don't recognize the output of the transform anymore. I would rather prefer a new dataframe where the new dummy columns have given their own name, such as Sex_male (1/0) Embarked_Q (1/0) and Embarked_S(1/0)

I'm only used to using `gretl`, there dummifying a variable and leaving out one option is very natural. I don't know in python if i'm doing it wrong or if this scenario is not part of the standard scikit toolkit. Any advice? Maybe I should write a custom encoder for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try and answer all your questions individually.

> Answer for Question 1

In your code you have used `fit_transform` method both on your train and test data which is not the correct way of doing it. Generally, `fit_transform` is applied only on your train data set, and it returns a transformer which is then just used to `transform` your test data set. When you apply `fit_transform` on your test data, you just transform your test data with just the options/levels of the categorical variables available only in your test data set and it is very much possible that your test data may not contain all options/levels of all categorical variables, due to which the dimension of your train and test data set will differ resulting in the error which you have got.

So the correct way of doing it would be:

```
X_train_t = ct.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_t  = ct.transform(X_test)
```

> Answer for Question 2

If you want to avoid the "dummy variable trap" you can make use of the parameter `drop` (by setting it to `first`) while creating the `OneHotEncoder` object in the `ColumnTransformer`, this will result in creating just one column for `sex` and two columns for `Embarked` since they have two and three options/levels respectively.

So the correct way of doing it would be:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop="first"), ['Sex','Embarked'])], remainder='passthrough')
```

> Answer for Question 3

As of now the `get_feature_names` method which can be reconstruct your data frame with new dummy columns is not implemented in`sklearn` yet. One work around for this would be to change the `reminder` to `drop` in the `ColumnTransformer` construction and construct your data frame separately as shown below:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop="first"), ['Sex', 'Embarked'])], remainder='drop')
A = pd.concat([X_train.drop(["Sex", "Embarked"], axis=1), pd.DataFrame(X_train_t, columns=ct.get_feature_names())], axis=1) 
A.head()
```

which will result in something like this:

[image]

Your final code will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

cols = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Embarked']

train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', usecols=cols)
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=[e for e in cols if e != 'Survived'])

cols = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Embarked']

train_df = train_df.dropna()
test_df = test_df.dropna()

train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True)

X_train = train_df.drop("Survived", axis=1)
Y_train = train_df["Survived"]
X_test = test_df.copy()

categorical_values = ['Sex', 'Embarked']
X_train_cont = X_train.drop(categorical_values, axis=1)
X_test_cont = X_test.drop(categorical_values, axis=1)

ct = ColumnTransformer([("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop="first"), categorical_values)], remainder='drop')

X_train_categorical = ct.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_categorical  = ct.transform(X_test)

X_train_t = pd.concat([X_train_cont, pd.DataFrame(X_train_categorical, columns=ct.get_feature_names())], axis=1)
X_test_t = pd.concat([X_test_cont, pd.DataFrame(X_test_categorical, columns=ct.get_feature_names())], axis=1)

logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000)
logreg.fit(X_train_t, Y_train)
Y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_t)

acc_log = round(logreg.score(X_train_t, Y_train) * 100, 2)

print(acc_log)

80.34
```

And when you do `X_train_t.head()` you get

[image]

Comment: Answer looks very good at first impression. I would like to do `fit` (of `fit_transform`) on both train and test data in case that test data contains an additional categorical value. Then use this fit for transform train and test separately. In your code does `fit_transform` save the "fit" into the ct object for later use in transform of test data?

Comment: Using `fit_transfom` on both train and test data set will result in `data leaking` issues. When you try to add the extra categorical values in the test data to your column transformation process your computed performance measure on the test data set is heavily biased and over inflated, You may not see the same performance of your model when you put your model for production as you would have observed in the test data set. And as you mentioned my code does `fit_transform` save the "fit" into the ct object for later use in transform of test data.

Comment: I tested this answer now. It's excellent. Thanks for the help. Bounty can not be awarded yet (16 hours).

Comment: Thank you, if the answer was helpful kindly mark it as a verified answer and give it an upvote so that it will be helpful for others who might visit this in the future.

Answer (score 4):

1. Recommended practice is suggested in @Parthasarathy Subburaj's answer but I have seen in Kaggle or other competition, where people fit on the complete data (train+test). If you want to try the same, use the following format

```
ct.fit(X_complete)
X_train_t, X_test_t  = ct.transform(X_test), ct.transform(X_test)
```

2. ya, use `drop='first'` to get over this issue. At the same time, remember this multicollinearity problem is not a big deal for non-linear models such as neural networks or even decision trees. I believe that is the reason why it is not kept as the default arg param value.
3. `get_feature_names` is not implemented exhaustively for pipelines and other stuffs in sklearn. Hence, they are supporting complete in `ColumnTransformer` as well.

Based on my experience, I had built this wrapper for `ColumnTransfomer`, which can support for even it has `pipelines` or `reminder=passthrough`.

This also picks up the feature names for `get_feature_names` instead of calling it as `x0, x1` because we know the actual column names inside `ColumnTransformer` using `_feature_names_in`.

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted

def _get_features_out(name, trans, features_in):
    if hasattr(trans, 'get_feature_names'):
        return [name + "__" + f for f in
                                  trans.get_feature_names(features_in)]
    else:
        return features_in


class NamedColumnTransformer(ColumnTransformer):
    def get_feature_names(self):
        check_is_fitted(self)
        feature_names = []
        for name, trans, features, _ in self._iter(fitted=True):
            if trans == 'drop':
                continue
            if trans == 'passthrough':
                feature_names.extend(self._feature_names_in[features])
            elif hasattr(trans, '_iter'):
                for _, op_name, t in trans._iter():
                    features=_get_features_out(op_name, t, features)
                feature_names.extend(features)
            elif not hasattr(trans, 'get_feature_names'):
                raise AttributeError("Transformer %s (type %s) does not "
                                     "provide get_feature_names."
                                     % (str(name), type(trans).__name__))
            else:
                feature_names.extend(_get_features_out(name, trans, features))

        return feature_names
```

Now, for your example,

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# you can fetch the titanic dataset using this
X, y = fetch_openml("titanic", version=1,
                    as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)

# removing the columns which you are not using 
X.drop(['name', 'ticket', 'cabin', 'boat', 'body', 'home.dest'],
       axis=1, inplace=True)

X.dropna(inplace=True)
X.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
y = y[X.index]

categorical_values = ['sex', 'embarked']

ct = NamedColumnTransformer([("onehot", OneHotEncoder(
    sparse=False, drop="first"), categorical_values)], remainder='passthrough')


clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', ct),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000))])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


clf[0].get_feature_names()
# ['onehot__sex_male',
#  'onehot__embarked_Q',
#  'onehot__embarked_S',
#  'pclass',
#  'age',
#  'sibsp',
#  'parch',
#  'fare']
```

```
pd.DataFrame(clf[0].transform(X_train), columns=clf[0].get_feature_names())
```

[image]

You can also try the `NamedColumnTransformer` for a more interesting example of `ColumnTransformer` [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py).

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. Your code seems useful for an even more elegant solution